# Using Partial View on 2 Differently Typed Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I have a Partial view that I would like to use on 2 different Stronly-Typed views.  The data being passed is just a simple ID integer, but when I try to render the data on View #2 I get an

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `CMESurvey.ViewModels.SurveyParticipantViewModel`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `CMESurvey.Models.SurveyProgramModel`.

Here is the partial view code that errors:

```
@Html.Partial("SurveyProgramSubNav", new {ProgramId = Model.ProgramId})
```

This code is in a differently strong typed from my Partial View Strong Type:

```
@model CMESurvey.Models.SurveyProgramModel
```

for the partial view, and:

```
@model CMESurvey.ViewModels.SurveyParticipantViewModel
```

For the view that I'm having trouble with.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
@Html.Partial("SurveyProgramSubNav", 
   new SurveyProgramModel {ProgramId = Model.ProgramId})
```

specify strong type of the model instead of automatic type.

Answer (score 0):

When working with PartialViews, it's better to avoid calling the model, since different views will have different models (mostly).
I'd recommend you to change the `Model.ProgramId` to `ViewBag.ProgramId` at the partial view and, at the actions, you populate this property like `ViewBag.ProgramId = whatever;`

To make things easier, you can work with Controller inheritance and place this set at your base controller.

Regards